How to upload and serve an html template in Google App Engine Go?
So I've copied my old GAE Go project to a new repo and for some reason all my html templates stopped working. Here is my simplified sample code - https://github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/blob/main/app/main.go . I'm guessing it's due to something in the app.yaml configuration changing over the years and me not being able to tell it to upload the html files to the server for parsing...
So simplifying, in my main file, I have:
var MainTemplate *template.Template

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    MainTemplate, _ = template.ParseFiles("html/main.html")
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    MainTemplate.Execute(w, nil)
}

I get a nil dereference error since MainTemplate is nil. The code runs just fine locally, so I'm guessing there is a problem parsing the file on GAE.
My app.yaml is basically:
runtime:     go122
app_engine_apis:  true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /html
  static_dir: html
- url: /res
  static_dir: res
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  login: optional

and the main files are located as follows:
└───app
    ├───html
    └───static

The main.go and app.yaml are under app and the main.html is under app/html.
My actual project has more html files in multiple folders so I wouldn't want to list them one by one as "static file, upload", so some kind of directory upload would be preferrable. I noticed during my search that I may also have to specify special access for the files for my app to be able to access them, but I'm not sure if that applies here?

Hmm, for some reason I think template parsin in init() failed, but when I moved that to the regular function it worked normally... Not sure why, it used to work just fine in the past...

Okay, the problem was slightly silly - Google App Engine changed what it sees as the "root" of the program.
For a long time it demanded to have the app folder be a sub-folder of the project and for you to put your main function and the app.yaml file in there. So if I asked for "html/main.html" it would get it from app/html folder just fine.
But that seems to have changed recently. Now I don't think the app folder is needed anymore, and it is definitely seen as a sub-folder of the project. So even if I have app.yaml under app, I still have to specify everything in relationship to the root folder. So I needed to change imports from html/* into app/html/* and similarly make app/html static. With that, everything works like it used to...
